# Node with phantom no default engine was specified

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I have the following node code:

```
    var express = require('express');
var app = module.exports = express();
var phantom = require('node-phantom');

    app.use('/', function (req, res) {
        if (typeof(req.query._escaped_fragment_) !== "undefined") {
            phantom.create(function (err, ph) {
                return ph.createPage(function (err, page) {
                    return page.open("https://example.com/#!" + req.query._escaped_fragment_, function (status) {
                        return page.evaluate((function () {
                            return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;
                        }), function (err, result) {
                            res.send(result);
                            return ph.exit();
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        } else
            res.render('index');
    });

    app.listen(3500);
    console.log('Magic happens on port ' + 3500);
```

This happens whenever i attempt to go to my domain. However when i go there i get the following error:

```
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
```

Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong?

Comment: Express is trying to call render, but you didn't specify which view engine to use.  That's what the error is.

Comment: @JamesLeClair im fairly new to this phantom and render do you know what render i should use to render HTML pages?

Comment: This isn't anything to do with phantom,  its an express error.  See my answer below for an idea of how to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express is trying to call render, but you didn't specify which view engine to use. That's what the error is

If you are using jade add this configuration after you invoke app

```
//change path to fit your use case of course
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

If you are just trying to send a static html file, use `res.sendFile()` instead

```
res.sendFile('/path/to/index.html')
```